# MacOS Terminal go to a folder with spaces and parenthesis

Tags: macos, terminal, directory

I'm trying to configure Cyberduck to read the Bookmark files from my Dropbox folder.

This is usually accomplished by this command:

```
defaults write ch.sudo.cyberduck application.support.path ~/Dropbox/Cyberduck
```

Super easy!!

But... Dropbox has since changed and if you have a Pro Account the Dropbox folder is renamed "Dropbox (Personal)".

I've tried to do this:

```
defaults write ch.sudo.cyberduck application.support.path ~/Dropbox\ \(Personal\)/
```

And I get this error:

```
not parse: [...]/Dropbox (Personal)/Apps/Cyberduck/.  Try single-quoting it.
```

I tried single quoting like this but same error:

```
defaults write ch.sudo.cyberduck application.support.path '~/Dropbox\ \(Personal\)/'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hm, `~/Dropbox\ \(Personal\)/` would definitely work in the Terminal / bash shell, however, I am not sure about cyberduck, sry. The " (Personal)" appendix ... is this normal? Also have the Pro version, running MacOS, and the directory is still `~/Dropbox`

Comment: @SebastianRaschka ok, it can be because probably you had Dropbox already installed, than you did the upgrade. But if you install it anew on another computer that happens: https://www.dropbox.com/help/4210

Comment: If you single quote, the tilde `~` won't get expanded. Use `'/Users/you/Dropbox...'`

Comment: I have run into the exact same problem with an enterprise folder for Dropbox. While I can cd to the directory no problem (and it reports back with the right name when I run pwd). I cannot get a "defaults write" to work with any combo of backslashes, single or double quotes or quoting only the part of the path with "Dropbox (Company Name)", nor with root or relative paths. So far it looks like no answers here have worked for anyone. The result is always: "Could not parse: […] Try single quoting it."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can single quote escape your parentheses by wrapping them in a double quote:

Instead of: `ln -s '/Users/username/Dropbox (Company Name)/' DropboxCompanyName`

Do: `ln -s "'/Users/username/Dropbox (Company Name)/'" DropboxCompanyName`

Notice the double quotes added to `/Users/username/Dropbox (Company Name)/`

Answer (score 1):

So I cannot find a way to do a "defaults write" to a path with parentheses, but I did this workaround and it seemed to work for me (in my case I needed to link to my enterprise Dropbox account):

cd to your home folder and create a symlink of the directory that has the parentheses:

```
ln -s '/Users/username/Dropbox (Company Name)/' DropboxCompanyName
```

At that point, I was able to do do a defaults write that wrote ~/DropboxCompanyName as part of the path and it worked just fine.

All that said, your personal folder already has a hidden symlink: "Dropbox" that's in the same directory and pointing to "Dropbox (Personal)", so you *should* be able to do you original command as such:

```
defaults write ch.sudo.cyberduck application.support.path ~/Dropbox/Cyberduck
```

… because the "Dropbox" part of the path should still lead to your personal folder. This both what I've observed locally (when viewing hidden files) and what Dropbox says on their site: https://www.dropbox.com/help/9031

Comment: Hello! You can get around the parentheses issue by wrapping the single quotes in double quotes. `ln -s "'/Users/username/Dropbox (Company Name)/'" DropboxCompanyName`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Unix in Terminal.

I have set up a folder of the same name in my Public Folder to test as shown below. 
[image]

Your current referencing to the folder would seem correct. Dragging the folder into the Terminal window current command line will automatically give you the correct referencing to that folder.

As an alternative I suggest putting the name of the folder in **double quotation** marks. Even though there are brackets in the name, there is no need to escape these characters in Unix in Terminal in this instance when using double quotation marks. This makes it easier to humanly type the correct reference.

To reference a folder in the image below, for example, the following referencing works for the cd (change directory command):

~/Public/"Dropbox (Personal)"

Hence I suggest try:

```
ch.sudo.cyberduck application.support.path ~/Public/"Dropbox (Personal)"
```

As for the rest of this command, I am not sure that ch is a valid Unix command. I do not yet have enough Unix experience to guide you from here.

Comment: I have the same result with `~/"Dropbox (Personale)"/Apps/Cyberduck`

Comment: OK, ch is for a C language Shell.

Comment: By same result do you mean success or failure? Also you have an extra e on the end of the file name.

Comment: I mean failure with the same error message. The "e" is because I'm italian an my folder is named `Dropbox (Personale)` by Dropbox. :)

Comment: Ok, cool. This command worked before for you, yet it seems the various means to correctly include the path have been tried. I am wondering if the issue is outside of the path addressing.  If you have recently upgraded to OSX 10.11, that has changed some system files around. Long shot, but just mentioning as I have reached my knowledge here.

Comment: tks. It worked on a different computer and I used to have the "Dropbox" folder, no "personal" s***t added... Tsk anyways

Answer (score 0):

you have to put "" in the whole address

more like this

```
ch.sudo.cyberduck application.support.path "~/Public/Dropbox (Personal)"
```

Comment: Same result:
$ defaults write ch.sudo.cyberduck application.support.path "~/Dropbox (Personale)/Apps/Cyberduck"
2016-06-04 11:24:31.972 defaults[1136:362232] Could not parse: ~/Dropbox (Personale)/Apps/Cyberduck.  Try single-quoting it.

Comment: No; the quotes prevent the shell from resolving `~`. Put that outside the quotes - `~/"Dropbox/etc (ad naus)"` - or use `$HOME` instead, which does get resolved even in double (but not in single!) quotes.

Comment: so, why don't put the address in absolute?

Comment: That's correct. I found out if you drag the folder into the terminal it gets you there with no pain..